# The redirect URI in the request does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client.

Tags: php, youtube-data-api

I am using the IDToken.PHP example in the Google API client library but everytime it says

> The redirect URI, https://example.com/youtube/idtoken.php in the
>   request does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client.

I have put both the https and https version of the URL in https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=xxx but it still does not work.

please help!

Comment: can you share your code here

Comment: http://www.w3resource.com/API/youtube/tutorial.php ....

Comment: my redirect uri in google developer console is `"http://localhost/wp-firebackup/oauth2callback/"` and same is passed to `$client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/wp-firebackup/oauth2callback/')` and its working, remember to keep trailing slash `'/'` at the end